# cURL error 6: Could not resolve host – Intermittent

Tags: guzzle

we've been using Laravel / Guzzle to handle all our jobs for over a year but over the past couple of weeks we've seen a complete failure down to 2 errors:

```
cURL error 6: Could not resolve host
cURL error 6: getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
```

Our jobs run on the hour and every job fails with the same error, once it starts it will continue to fail all jobs.

Restarting the server fix the issue for a few days but it's just come back.

Anything to check first? Pretty puzzled.

Comment: if it is coming rarely then it may be due to external server, handle the error using try catch